Cannot access balance in BTC Core/Sparrow Wallet/Seedsigner
My saga begins thus - February 2024 i make a series of deposits from my Trezor wallet to my newly formed Seedsigner/Sparrow Wallet/Bitcoin Core node using Seed-Words & Passphrase in BIP39, everything is good & i can signin & out of my new wallet with full balance showing after the transactions with Trezor,after this last viewing of those successful transactions i do not use that node again, i just left it running & never attempted to check the balance again until 2 days ago, in the last 9mths i have had another separate node running specifically in BTC Testnet, running weekly practice transactions for the sake of keeping up to speed, both nodes are HP T630 Thin Clients running Linux Debian 12, please note i updated all software including BTC Core/Seedsigner/Sparrow Wallet to the latest versions on time.
The Crux is...when i decided to log into the Mainnet Node i forgot to change the setting on the Seedsigner from Testnet to Mainnet, so i entered the correct Seed & Passphrase with both fingerprints correct only to see a wallet with no transactions...i shortly thereafter found my error in not changing the Seedsigner setting from Testnet to Mainnet, so i promptly changed it back to Mainnet, deleted the wallet from Sparrow Wallet then entered my Seed & Passphrase in correct order with Fingerprints matching only to come across the same uninviting wallet that had appeared before, namely no transactions being listed, everything else had been changed correctly namely the BTC Core Config to server=1 etc.
I had the original Trezor Seed which i had used to transfer earlier in Feb 2024 so i entered that Seed into Seedsigner/Sparrow/BTC Core & up came those transactions i had sent in Feb 2024 to my SS/Sparrow/BTC Core wallet.
The question i am asking the Learned Folk here are, is there a way i can regain my wallet back with its full balance? i am NOT tech Savvy & any advice is appreciated! thank you.


is there a way i can regain my wallet back with its full balance?

You could restore your wallet backups on new equipment.
